# Detect if a node when dropped/moved intersects another node - mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraphx, jgraph

I am trying to detect if any part of cell node intersects with another cell when u move a cell and some of its body intersects with another node. I tried to write my own custom `mouseUp` function such that if the there's some intersection, I'll display an error saying that its allowed. Below is the code i wrote. It doesn't work perfectly. one time when it works well is if I  put a node on the center on another node but other times when I put a node on the far edge of another node it doesn't work.

```
const mouseUp = graph.graphHandler.mouseUp;
graph.graphHandler.mouseUp = function(...args) {
      const target = graph.getCellAt(args[1].graphX, args[1].graphY);
      if (target) {
        alert('not allowed');
        graph.graphHandler.reset();
      } else {
        mouseUp.apply(this, args);
      }
    };
```